# MetadataService mock class

Tags: metadata

I tried creating a mock class for a class that uses MetadataService but after too many attempts, I stll can't get it. Can anyone please give me a sample mock class for these lines?

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = MetadataServiceExamples.createService();
(MetadataService.CustomField) service.readMetadata('CustomField', new String[] { fieldName }).getRecords()[0];
```

for MetadataServiceExamples.createService():

```
public static MetadataService.MetadataPort createService()
{
    MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
    service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
    service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
    return service;
}
```

I just dont know what to do anymore. I hope anuone can give me a sample to get the idea.

Comment: How are we supposed to help you if we don't know what the problem is? It's great that you shared your code, but without a specific error, it may be hard to diagnose without an error.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a sample `MetadataService` mock class:

```
/**
 * Basic mock for the operations presently used.
 */
public class MetadataServiceMock implements WebServiceMock {

    public static final String[] RECORD_TYPE_FULL_NAMES = new String[] {
        'cve__BenefitClaimed__c.cve__ShortTermDisability'
    };
    public static final String[] CUSTOM_FIELD_FULL_NAMES = new String[] {
        'Contact.Email',
        'cve__BenefitClaimed__c.cve__DateOfDiagnosis__c'
    };

    public void doInvoke(
            Object stub,
            Object request,
            Map<String, Object> response,
            String endpoint,
            String soapAction,
            String requestName,
            String responseNS,
            String responseName,
            String responseType
            ) {

        if (request instanceof MetadataService.readMetadata_element) {
            response.put('response_x', readResponse(request));
        } else if (request instanceof MetadataService.updateMetadata_element) {
            response.put('response_x', updateResponse(request));
        } else if (request instanceof MetadataService.upsertMetadata_element) {
            response.put('response_x', upsertResponse(request));
        } else {
            System.assert(false, 'Unexpected request ' + request);
        }
    }

    // Implements couple of requests
    private MetadataService.IReadResponseElement readResponse(Object request) {

        MetadataService.readMetadata_element r = (MetadataService.readMetadata_element) request;

        if (r.type_x == 'RecordType') {

            MetadataService.PicklistValue picklistValue = new MetadataService.PicklistValue();
            picklistValue.fullName = 'Pending';

            MetadataService.RecordTypePicklistValue recordTypePicklistValue = new MetadataService.RecordTypePicklistValue();
            recordTypePicklistValue.picklist = 'cve__Status__c';
            recordTypePicklistValue.values = new MetadataService.PicklistValue[] {picklistValue};

            MetadataService.RecordType recordType = new MetadataService.RecordType();
            recordType.fullName = RECORD_TYPE_FULL_NAMES[0];
            recordType.picklistValues = new MetadataService.RecordTypePicklistValue[] {
                recordTypePicklistValue
            };

            MetadataService.ReadRecordTypeResult result = new MetadataService.ReadRecordTypeResult();
            result.records = new MetadataService.RecordType[] {
                recordType
            };

            MetadataService.readRecordTypeResponse_element responseElement = new MetadataService.readRecordTypeResponse_element();
            responseElement.result = result;

            return responseElement;

        } else if (r.type_x == 'CustomField') {

            MetadataService.ReadCustomFieldResult result = new MetadataService.ReadCustomFieldResult();
            result.records = new MetadataService.CustomField[] {
                createContactEmailField(),
                createBenefitClaimedDateOfDiagnosisField()
            };

            MetadataService.readCustomFieldResponse_element responseElement = new MetadataService.readCustomFieldResponse_element();
            responseElement.result = result;

            return responseElement;

        } else {

            System.assert(false, 'Unexpected read type ' + r.type_x);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static MetadataService.CustomField createContactEmailField() {

        MetadataService.CustomField f = new MetadataService.CustomField();
        f.type_x = String.valueOf(DisplayType.Email);
        f.fullName = CUSTOM_FIELD_FULL_NAMES[0];
        f.label = 'Email';
        f.length = 80;
        f.encrypted = false;

        return f;
    }

    public static MetadataService.CustomField createBenefitClaimedDateOfDiagnosisField() {

        MetadataService.CustomField f = new MetadataService.CustomField();
        f.type_x = String.valueOf(DisplayType.Date);
        f.fullName = CUSTOM_FIELD_FULL_NAMES[1];
        f.label = 'Date';
        f.encrypted = false;

        return f;
    }

    // Does nothing except return success
    private MetadataService.updateMetadataResponse_element updateResponse(Object request) {

        MetadataService.SaveResult result = new MetadataService.SaveResult();
        result.success = true;

        MetadataService.updateMetadataResponse_element responseElement = new MetadataService.updateMetadataResponse_element();
        responseElement.result = new MetadataService.SaveResult[] {result};

        return responseElement;
    }

    // Does nothing except return success
    private MetadataService.upsertMetadataResponse_element upsertResponse(Object request) {

        MetadataService.UpsertResult result = new MetadataService.UpsertResult();
        result.success = true;

        MetadataService.upsertMetadataResponse_element responseElement = new MetadataService.upsertMetadataResponse_element();
        responseElement.result = new MetadataService.UpsertResult[] {result};

        return responseElement;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for this, got me out of a jam i was in. If you wanted to make custom field a picklist value, how would you go around adding values to the custom field to check? similar to what you did with recordtype?

Comment: or a global value set? i wish there was a gist or something on the mdapi but nothing